# Cannot instantiate class error

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

This is the android manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/pic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.thenewboaton.travis.abc"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.thenewboaton.traivs.splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.thenewboaton.Splash" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Main java class named MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        int counter;
        Button add;
        Button sub;
        TextView display;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            counter=0;
            add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
            sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub); 
            display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter++;      
                    display.setText("Your total is "+counter);

                }
            });

            sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter--;
                    display.setText("Your total is "+counter);

                }

             });


        }//method
    }//class

    Finally the logcat:

06-17 18:51:51.427: E/AndroidRuntime(358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 18:51:51.427: E/AndroidRuntime(358): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboaton.travis/com.thenewboaton.travis.abc}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thenewboaton.travis.abc in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thenewboaton.travis-1.apk]
06-17 18:51:51.427: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
```

so i tried varying the class names here and there and also the activity name. As soon as the emulator starts the error comes saying the Launcher has failed and the app doesn't start off at all .. i cant remember the EXACT change i did  before this error started .. 
anyone can help me out on this ?
I'd be glad if anyone can figure this out . thanks :)

Comment: which one is your launcher activity ??splash or abc? and where is MainActivity in Android Manifest?

Comment: Your class is called `MainActivity`, not `abc`... and you have a misspelling in your Manifest: `traivs` vs. `travis`.

Comment: @jash, consider reading [Building your first Android App](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=android%20hello%20world&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fbasics%2Ffirstapp%2F&ei=ERK_UebIKMmnqQHSxoG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNEZV1iUjZRZ8A0ibYpa5d2Cek6hCg&sig2=5R-ZBtY0eTCE618C-22pLQ&bvm=bv.47883778,d.aWM)

Answer (score 1):

You need to point the `AndroidManifest` at `MainActivity`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Or, if you Activity is called *abc* or *splash*, and is located in your main package, you can use:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".abc"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        ...
    </activity>
```

and

```
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        ...
    </activity>
```

Comment: hey, i did all those changes,a  new error is coming .. these are the first few lines of the logcat. Is this causing a problem?06-17 19:52:15.410: I/Process(400): Sending signal. PID: 400 SIG: 9
06-17 19:52:47.049: W/dalvikvm-heap(454): dvmMalloc(39923728/0x02613010): someone's allocating a huge buffer
06-17 19:52:47.049: I/dalvikvm-heap(454): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 39923728-byte allocation
06-17 19:52:47.188: D/dalvikvm(454): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 51K, 5% free 8637K/9027K, paused 139ms
06-17 19:52:47.188: E/dalvikvm-heap(454): Out of memory on a 39923728-byte allocation.

Comment: this is the latter half :06-17 19:52:47.349: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboaton.travis/com.thenewboaton.travis.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView

Comment: @jash, this is a problem with `ActionBarView`, which you reference in your layout file. To fix, either remove the reference in your layout file (short fix), or post a new question about how to fix your `ActionBarView` class (also post this error there).

Answer (score -1):

Your manifest points to two activities: "abc" and "splash" but your source code is called MainActivity. Either renmae MainActivity to abc or edit the manifest to point to MainActivity instead of abc.